# Can I set HttpContext.Current.User outside of Application_AuthenticateRequest in an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net, lifecycle

After Googling around I found out that (naturally) opinions vary. So here goes:

Is it OK to be setting `HttpContext.Current.User` *not* inside `AuthenticateRequest` event handler, but someplace else (like `BeginRequest` or any other event handler)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, setting `Current.User` somewhere other than in `AuthenticateRequest` leads to all kinds of elusive bugs under IIS 7.0. These are very hard to pinpoint, but a juxtaposition of all kinds of Authentication methods that IIS/ASP.NET support plus Integrated vs Classic pipeline modes plus .NET versions... All in all, a bad idea.

Comment: +1 Coming to conclusions like this "All in all, a bad idea" is what makes good programmers better, not insisting/forcing on an idea that is bug prone right off the bat. You are saving a huge amount of time, money, and headaches down the line by not introducing that risk (the part that says "elusive bugs") in your systems.

Comment: It's annoying that ASP.NET used a single `HttpContext` class full of exposed mutable state (such as `User`) for all steps of the ASP.NET Request lifecycle. I wish they'd use different immutable classes for each step, which would prevent confusion like this.